# can i print a setter value (sysout) or do i have to use only getters in order to get an output ? (java)

Tags: java, printing, setter, getter-setter

I have just recently learned about setter , getters and this.(somthing).
I having quite a hard time undersatnding when to use getters and when to use setters .
Another thing , `can i use setter method to print out ?`

**For Example :**

```
 class workerId {
private int workerAge;
private String workerName;
private int workerIde;

public void setWorkerAge(int newAge) {
    newAge = workerAge;
}

public void setWorkerName(String newName) {
    newName = workerName;
}

public int setIde(int ide) {
    ide = workerIde;
    return ide;

 }
}

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    workerId worker1 = new workerId();
    worker1.setWorkerAge(41);
    worker1.setWorkerName("dan ");
    worker1.setIde(318574524);

    System.out.println(worker1.setIde());

    }

}
```

the system out print shows an error and i didnt understand why , is it because only getters can be used in the sysout command ?

Comment: My hint: Go back and restart learning basics of programming

Comment: setIde is a function that takes an argument. You should provide that argument..
You could use a getIde function for getting the result and printing it

Comment: getter and setter just represent a common programming practice, setting and getting the value of a class instance variable. You could name them different if you´d want to. The more important part is the returntype (`ìnt`, `void`, `String`) etc. In your current case you are calling `setIde()`, but your method is defined as `setIde(int)`, where you are missing the `int` parameter. additionally, setter normally are of the returntype `void`.

Comment: And your setters  are constructed incorrectly..you should assign the method parameter to the class member, like `workerAge = newAge;`..

Comment: @bub considering the fact that i started learning java 3 days ago , this is me learning the basics -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense intended, but your setters are all wrong. You should assign your properties to the values passed in the setter, not setting the value again. So your code should look like this:

```
class workerId {
  private int workerAge;
  private String workerName;
  private int workerIde;

  public void setWorkerAge(int newAge) {
    workerAge = newAge;
  }

  public void setWorkerName(String newName) {
    workerName = newName;
  }

  public int setIde(int ide) {
    workerIde = ide;
  }
}
```

If you need getters, it should look like this:

```
class workerId {
  private int workerAge;
  private String workerName;
  private int workerIde;

  public void setWorkerAge(int newAge) {
    workerAge = newAge;
  }

  public void setWorkerName(String newName) {
    workerName = newName;
  }

  public int setIde(int ide) {
    workerIde = ide;
  }
  public int getIde() {
    return workerIde;
  }
}
```

Then you can print, e.g. `System.out.println(worker1.getIde());`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a getter method to get the values.

```
class workerId {
private int workerAge;
private String workerName;
private int workerIde;

    public void setWorkerAge(int newAge) {
        workerAge = newAge;
    }

    public void setWorkerName(String newName) {
         workerName=newName;
    }
    public int getIde() {
    return workerIde;
    }    

    public void setIde(int ide) {
        workerIde = ide;

     }
    }

    public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        workerId worker1 = new workerId();
        worker1.setWorkerAge(41);
        worker1.setWorkerName("dan ");
        worker1.setIde(318574524);

        System.out.println(worker1.getIde());

        }

    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work ,
complier says : "Ide cannot be resolved to a variable" 
can you explain ?

Comment: @xepo sorry, i thought the error was there only in the getter function. Your setter functions were also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class workerId {
    private int workerAge;
    private String workerName;
    private int workerIde;

    public void setWorkerAge(int newAge) {
        this.workerAge = newAge;
    }

    public void setWorkerName(String newName) {
        this.workerName = newName;
    }

    public int setIde(int ide) {
        this.workerIde = ide;
        return this.workerIde;

     }
    }


    public class Car {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        workerId worker1 = new workerId();
        worker1.setWorkerAge(41);
        worker1.setWorkerName("dan ");
        worker1.setIde(318574524);

    System.out.println(worker1.setIde(56));
    }

}
```